# Is it possible to re-generate a jhipster jdl file from an existing jhipster project?

Tags: jhipster

I'm new to jhipster, but I recently started working on a jhipster-generated project where the previous person added changes to the entity manually rather than using jhipster. I'm wondering if it's possible to update the jdl and json files to reflect the current entity.

Comment: You can export JDL from an existing project. https://www.jhipster.tech/jdl/getting-started#exporting-to-a-jdl-file

Comment: @MattRaible I tried this and what it generated look exactly the same as the current(outdated) jdl file

Comment: There's no way for JDL export to retrofit manual changes made to generated code, if you want to do it you must do it manually but I don't think it will have much interest. Customizing generated code is  normal and expected in a JHipster project lifecycle.